# How is a Elimination and Lower Triangluar Matrix related?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say for example I have a matrix,
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&c\\
d&e&f\\
g&h&i\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

 We can write a decomposistion for this matrix as: $\\A = LU$

Elimination matrix for this can be written like this:
$\\EA = U$

I want to know is there a relation between ***'E'*** and ***'L'*** in this particular scenario, because my Professor is able to find it quite simply when talking about these.

Comment: We have $A=LU=L(EA)=(LE)A$. If $A$ is invertible we obtain $LE=I$, so that $L=E^{-1}$.

Comment: @Dietrich_Burde yes brother, the problem however is that, that is what actually the professor told us? I am wondering that how can that relation be proved!?

Comment: You ask: "I want to know is there a relation between E and L in this particular scenario, because my Professor ...". The answer is yes, there is a relation, and we have a proof for it - see above.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry! I didn't saw it properly, actually, I was on phone so the LaTeX didn't render properly! Thanks for help